# Tokenizing sentences from a txt file, and getting the "expected string or bytes-like object" error

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I thought I had a really straight-forward code for opening a file, reading it, and tokenizing it into sentences.

```
import nltk
text = open('1865-Lincoln.txt', 'r')
tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
print(tokens)
```

But I just keep getting the crazy long error that ends with

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a read command between open and tokens.

```
fileObj = open('1865-Lincoln.txt', 'r')
text = fileObj.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

You were just opening the text file and not reading the same meaning the content of the same file would not get recorded as a string and also you were just passing your file to nltk to tokenize sentences which is only possible when you provide nltk with string type input. Hope you understand. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `read()` function in order read the content from your file afterwards it will allow to tokenize your sentences via `nltk.sent_tokenize` package. Re-generated your code as under:

```
import nltk
filex = open('1865-Lincoln.txt', 'r')
text = filex.read()
tokens = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
print(tokens)
```